# What is the average percent of value an employee makes which he gets on salary (called)?

Tags: reference-request, data-request, definition, productivity

I'm looking for any statistics showing the average percent of money employees get from the monetary value they create, primarily from the US or EU. Is there a term for this ratio?

Answer (score 5):

You are most likely looking for labor or wage share defined as the ratio of labor costs to nominal GDP. It basically expresses how much share of nominal GDP gets captured by labor.

You can find the data for the labor share in the US [here](https://www.bls.gov/opub/ted/2017/mobile/labor-share-of-output-has-declined-since-1947.htm), under that bit of text (for some reason I could not find direct link to pure dataset). The data are from the US bureau of labor statistics.